# How to convert raw pcap file to bag file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, velodyne-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this in one window: end of file reached -- done reading.
but the recording windows remains: Recording to grabacion.bag. and never finish
I finish it manually and nothing appear when I rosplay it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260432/how-to-convert-raw-pcap-file-to-bag-file?/) by [Pelacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/28393/pelacho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question answers for a VLP-16:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/213080/convert-raw-velodyne-vlp16-pcap-to-bagfile/

If you have a different model and can't figure out what the equivalent commands would be, please comment or edit your question. Be sure to mention which model you are using.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0